# How to send chunk files in web api in android?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, chunking, dataoutputstream

I'm sending a files that is greater than 2mb. In able to send this file I need to divide this file into smaller pieces with the size of 2mb per pieces[chunks] and send it by chunk. I already divided the files into smaller chunks and send it to web server, but the problem is when I already getting  the response the file size is getting bigger while sending the file chunk by chunk.But the file size of every chunk is 2mb so I'm wondering why this happening. **The expected file length is the length of the specific chunk that I send and the chunk length is the addition size of all the chunk that is already send.** Here I got so far:

```
        File mFile = new File(samplefile);

        int mychunkSize = 2048 * 1024;
        final long size = mFile.length();
        final long chunks = size < mychunkSize? 1: (mFile.length() / mychunkSize);

        int chunkId = 0;
        int ordername = 0;

        int bytesRead = 0, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;


        byte[] buffer;

        int maxBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

        if (size > maxBufferSize){ //if file size is greater than 2mb
            try {
                splitFiles = ChunkFiles.splitFile(mFile);
                String chunkedfiles="";
                int i = 0;

                for (i=0; i < splitFiles.size(); i++) {

                    chunkedfiles = splitFiles.get(i);


                    try {
                        File theChunkFiles = new File(chunkedfiles);
                        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(theChunkFiles);

                        bytesAvailable = stream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        int bufferlength = buffer.length;

                         // read file and write it into form...
                         bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        ordername++;

                        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                        String twoHyphens = "--";
                        String boundary =  "-------------------------acebdf13572468";// random data


                         String param3 = mFile.getName();
                         String param4 = samplefile;
                         String chunkFileName = theChunkFiles.getName();

                             URL url = new URL(urlString);

                             // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                             // Allow Inputs
                             conn.setDoInput(true);
                             // Allow Outputs
                             conn.setDoOutput(true);
                             // Don't use a cached copy.
                             conn.setUseCaches(false);
                             // Use a post method.
                             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                             String encoded = Base64.encodeToString((_username+":"+_password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP); 
                             conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
                             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                             conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);


                             dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

                             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fieldNameHere\";filename=\"" + chunkFileName + "\"" + lineEnd); // filename is the Name of the File to be uploaded
                            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd);
                            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                                bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            }


                                var = bufferSize;

                            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                            // Send parameter #chunks
                            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chunk\"" + lineEnd);

                            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                            dos.writeBytes(chunkId + lineEnd);
                            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                            // Send parameter #name
                            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"" + lineEnd);

                            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                            dos.writeBytes("ForFiddlerTest19VIDEO_20130711_151315_-2073548175.mp4" + lineEnd);



                            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                            // close streams

                            chunkId++;


                             is = conn.getInputStream();

                          // retrieve the response from server
                          int ch;

                          StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                          while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                          String s=b.toString();
                          Log.i("Response",s);
                         //stream.close();
                         is.close();
                         dos.close();



                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        System.out.println("From CLIENT REQUEST:" + ex);
                    }catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("From CLIENT REQUEST:" + ioe);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("From CLIENT REQUEST:", e.toString());
                    }



                }
                dos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Here is the sample Response I've got:**

```
{"Filename":"ForFiddlerTest19VIDEO_20130711_151315_-2073548175.mp4","ChunkId":2,"ChunkLength":2097152,"FileLength":6291456}
```

The file length is incrementing instead of the chunk length

Comment: Are you sure you did not mix up the meaning of the numbers? Seems odd to me that the chunk size is the length of the file and the file size is the length of the chunk.

Comment: all i'm doing is sending the file chunk 1 by 1 and write it in bytes on the dataoutputstream

Answer (score 0):

```
"ChunkLength":2097152,"FileLength":6291456
```

Chunk length is constant - 2 MB and file length returned by server is incrementing because  probably server joins chunks into single file - appends each new chunk at the end of final file so with each request you get new, larger file length in response while chunk length is constant.

Comment: do you have an idea how Can the response chunklength will going to increment instead of a file length because the file length of chunk Im going to send is 2mb and everytime I send the chunk files the chunk length will get the size of all the chunk I've sent

Comment: Is the server prepared also by you? What is returned in ChunkLength in response when you upload file in 1MB chunks? I think that the server returns just the size of received chunk in ChunkLength field.